# How to quickly see that a function is linear?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

All these functions are $0$ in the point $(0,0)$.
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^2}$$

$$g(x,y)=\frac{x^4}{x^2+y^2}$$

$$h(x,y)=\frac{x^2y}{x^2+y^4}$$

$$i(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{x^2+y^4}$$

How can I quickly see if functions like these are linear or not ? Are there any quick tricks ?

By linear I mean: $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b)$ and $f(\alpha x)=\alpha f(x)$

Comment: Without additional info, they are not defined at (0,0).

Comment: By linearity, do you mean $f(ax+by,z) = af(x,z) + bf(y,z)$?

Comment: @AdamYac Read the first sentence.

Comment: @90intuition Your definition of linear is for functions of a single (possibly vector-valued) variable, which your functions certainly are not.  Do you mean bilinear (linear in each variable), or just linear in the vector $[x,y]$?  Either way, this seems like a very odd thing to ask.

Comment: your definition is for single variable. Do you mean linear in each variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

None of these are linear. Use the point $(1,1)$ and the fact that $(1,1) = (1,0) + (0,1)$ to demonstrate that $f(1,1) \ne f(1,0) + f(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

$h(1,0)=h(0,1)=0$, so if $h$ were linear, it would be identically zero. Next, $f(0,1)=0$, so if $f$ were linear, $f(x,y)=xf(1,0)$. You will not have a hard time finding counterexamples to that equation! The others can be handled the same way.

Answer (score 1):

One of these functions is a homogeneous rational function of degree $1$, which might be interpreted as "linear" in certain contexts (e.g. linear growth, linear scaling).  But this is certainly not what you claim as the working definition of "linear" (which you have not been perfectly clear on).